# How to set client info while using JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have an mail account can be managed by mail client foxmail, a mail desktop client by Tencent.
But when I using JavaMail to connect to the IMAP server, the connection request is denied by the server saying that the client is not an authorized one.

Is it possible to set some properties to make the IMAP server take my javamail client as an authorized one ?

Comment: it seems that javamail does not support this kind of self declaim? http://connector.sourceforge.net/doc-files/Properties.html

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "self declaim".  Not that the properties supported by JavaMail are in the javadocs for the packages corresponding to each of the protocol providers; the [JavaMail FAQ has links](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sundocs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server might be using the [IMAP ID](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2971.txt) command to identify the client.  Both IMAPStore and IMAPFolder include an [id method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore.html#id-java.util.Map-) that allows you to issue the IMAP ID command.  You'll probably need to call it right after connecting and right after opening a folder.  You'll have to figure out what foxmail is sending if you want to send the same thing to "fake it".

Comment: In fact, I do not want to have my client faked as foxmail. I just try to make the mail server take my mail client as an normal client other than some kind of mail robot. Is this possible?

Comment: we are building an web app that receive the users mail boxes automaticlly.. I am quite sure that we are  not building EDM system ...

Answer (score 0):

```
DEBUG IMAP: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "imap.exmail.qq.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 IDLE XAPPLEPUSHSERVICE ID UIDPLUS AUTH=LOGIN NAMESPACE] QQMail IMAP4Server ready
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: LOGIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=imap.exmail.qq.com, user=moretradetest@yonanac.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: mechanism PLAIN disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.plain.disable
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE LOGIN command result: A0 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 X-NETSCAPE NAMESPACE MAILBOX-REFERRALS SCAN SORT THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND ID UIDPLUS] User <login> authenticated
A1 ID ("vendor" "MaiQing Tech ltd." "name" "MaiqingCRM" "version" "2.1.3")
* ID NIL
A1 OK ID completed
```

does the above log means that my id methods works for the mail server ?

Comment: The server took it.  Can you then open a mailbox?  If so, then I guess it's doing the right thing.  What does the debug output look like when it fails as you described in your original question?

Comment: by adding the other three parameters, os,os-version,contact, the imap server has taken my Javamail imap client as an authorized one. Thanks a lot. BTW, is there some similar setting/method for the smtp client?